# Does a new line character affect Postgres LIKE text search?

Tags: postgresql

So I have the following stored in a text column in Postgres...

```
This is a sentence.\nAnd here we start a new sentence.\nThen finally we have a third sentence.
```

Will those `\n` affect a `LIKE` query on that column?

i.e. `SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE (info LIKE '%sentence%')`

The reason I ask is I want the line breaks for properly formatting the output of the text, but obviously don't want them screwing up search.

Comment: `\n` is a character like any other. How do you see that causing problems in your query?

Comment: @AndreFeijo So `\nAnd` is treated as `\n` and `And` as opposed to `nAnd`?

Comment: `\n` will never be a `n`. If it's next to a word, they will be treated as different things `\n` and `And`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you store line breaks as line breaks it should not mess up with your query.

```
CREATE TABLE example(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   text TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO example (text) VALUES (E'This is a sentence.\nAnd here we start a new sentence.\nThen finally we have a third sentence.')

SELECT * FROM example WHERE text LIKE '%nAnd%'; -- 0 records returned
SELECT * FROM example WHERE text LIKE '%And%'; -- 1 record returned
```

Please note the `E` before the string when I inserted it into the table.